# PhpStorm - How to show files in alphabetic order?

Tags: netbeans, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, phpstorm-2016.3

In NetBeans 8.2 all files are shown in their alphabetic order, this is very useful because I can find a file extremely fast.

[image: NetBeans]

However, in PhpStorm this is not the case as you can see here:

[image: PhpStorm]

How can I enable this feature?

Comment: Those are editor tabs ... and they are listed in the same order as you arrange them. If you want alphabetical order -- chose `Sort Tabs by Filename` (by right clicking on editor tab). This will be applied to **all** tabs and not those that are currently hidden. There is no option to only sort hidden tabs in alphabetical order AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are editor tabs and they are listed in that drop-down list in the same order as you arrange them.

If you want alphabetical order -- choose `Sort Tabs by Filename` from Editor Tab context menu (right clicking on editor tab).

**Note:** this will be applied to ALL tabs and not only those that are currently hidden (my impression from NetBeans screenshot).

There is no option to sort only hidden tabs in alphabetical order.

---

*Possible alternative* to managing tabs/navigating between the files is to use `View | Recent Files` (<kbd>Ctr + E</kbd> using Default keymap) and/or `Navigate | File/Class...`.

This depends what you prefer/how you used to manage your files.

These popups can be used even with Editor Tabs hidden (e.g. when you need maximum space for editor to see your code).

---

Some useful links to check:

- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Navigating+through+a+PhpStorm+Project
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/managing-editor-tabs.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/navigating-through-the-source-code.html

Comment: That worked but now I can't move the tabs anymore. it is solved much better in Netbeans.

Comment: That's true -- once activated it's enforced this way. The only thing that comes into my mind -- activate and deactivate that option again .. but if you need to do it often then maybe better try using `View | Recent` instead (it supports quick search -- just start typing)